# How to update a p:slider from the p:inputNumber it is for?

Tags: javascript, primefaces

We would like to use Primefaces' slider.

We want to use comma (",") decimal separator instead of dot (".")

As suggested in other posts on stackoverflow we replaced the InputText with InputNumber.

We noticed that writing manually the number inside the input, the slider does not set automatically (with InputText, it does).

We noticed that in the showcase
https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/slider.xhtml
the third example uses InputNumber and has the same problem.

Anyone knows some workaround?
(Even on client side...)

```xml
<p:inputNumber  id="decimal" value="#{sliderView.number2}" decimalSeparator="," thousandSeparator="."/>
<p:slider for="decimal" minValue="0.2" maxValue="7.1" step="0.1" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for reporting. I have created this issue and PR:

Issue: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/6397

PR: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/pull/6398

if you need this fix right now just add this JS to your code:

```js
PrimeFaces.widget.InputNumber.prototype.setValueToHiddenInput = function(value) {
    this.hiddenInput.val(value);
    this.hiddenInput.trigger('change');
};
```